# how to debug a specific api in golang?

Tags: api, debugging, go

my wired situation is, the online service is working now, and everyday i can find a few `500` error reports like below:

```
2018-12-19 00:00:01     [ERROR] path[/vplay/getIdsInfo/?type=vlist&ids=31105228] err[runtime error: index out of range] stack[
goweb.(*RouterTab).ServeHTTP.func3.1:/home/tanxiaolong/golib/src/goweb/router.go:352
runtime.call64:/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:574
runtime.gopanic:/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:505
runtime.panicindex:/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:28
models.(*VplayModel).AssembleData:/home/tanxiaolong/golib/src/vplay/models/vplay.go:757
controllers.(*VplayController).GetIdsInfoAction:/home/tanxiaolong/golib/src/vplay/controllers/vplay.go:652
runtime.call32:/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:573
reflect.Value.call:/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:447
reflect.Value.Call:/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:308
goweb.(*RouterTab).ServeHTTP.func3:/home/tanxiaolong/golib/src/goweb/router.go:370
runtime.goexit:/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361]      (goweb/router.go:353)
```

i can find which api by log, but it returns `200` and correct response data if request it with the same query data as `500` requests by myself or wrk or ab.

i don't know how to debug this bug..

any suggestions on api debugging??

many thanks!

Comment: we need the code that generates the runtime error.

Comment: from the stack trace it's clear that the panic happen on `router.go:352`. we still need the code. not just the stack trace.

Comment: i found that bug along with the stack tips~  thank your tips too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're handling errors you can use:

> err.(*errors.Error).ErrorStack()

to return the stacktrace. With that you can get the line in which your API in some cases gets an index out of range error.

Comment: i used a error stack print,and i pick the one i understand attached. :-P
i dont know why i curl the api with 200 returns and the online service is sometime 500 returns.
i doubt that the online requests mess the goroutines up, but i have no proofs..

Comment: Nice, now we need the file vplay.go in the line 652 and everything related to it.

Comment: ah, i found the bug~ indeed a index out of a slice. thank you so much!